# How to iterate a formula based on a variable range table (columns & rows) until it returns zero?

Tags: vba, excel

Background: I have several tables in Sheet1, with each table representing a company sector (Data: absolute % variation of each company Mkt cap). My objective is to create a correlation matrix based on each sector.

**Based on these tables I'm trying to create a VBA function that could iterate a formula over a variable range of rows and columns (nb columns = nb rows) until the formula returns zero**

**CODE**

```
Sub Correlation_Matrix_test()

    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(INDIRECT(R2C1&""[""&R3C&""]"")=INDIRECT(R2C1&""[""&RC1&""]"")),--(INDIRECT(R2C1&""[""&R3C&""]"")<>0),--(INDIRECT(R2C1&""[""&RC1&""]"")<>0))/COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(R2C1&""[""&R3C&""]""),""<>0"",INDIRECT(R2C1&""[""&RC1&""]""),""<>0""),0)"
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B4:B126") ' range would be from row B4 to row B?(until formula returns ZERO)

    Range("B4:B126").Select  ' here we would take the range B4:B?

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B4:DT126") ' And autofill until the last column of the variable range, B4:??

End Sub
```

Small example to better understand the problem - Sheet2

[image: Small example to better understand the problem - Sheet2]

Comment: I still don't get it. How does table 2 fit into this (via the indirect?) ? And your code as written would overwrite this table?

Comment: Do not pay attention to the formula...  I am just looking for a way to iterate a formula through columns and rows until the formula returns zero

Comment: Table2 just shows a small sample of the problem

Comment: So in this case would you define the loop range as B4:D6 and terminate looping when formula evaluates to 0 or hits end of range?  In the example given, can it evaluate to 0 before termination?

Comment: In this case the the formula would return ZERO in  E4, E5, E6, B7, C7 and D7 for example

Comment: Sorry for all the questions but you require it to terminate when evaluates to zero it should only return one zero and in which cell would it be at the point it did so? Ooohhhh.....unless it is recursively called.....

Comment: I am relying on the result of the formula rather than on the range since it will vary depending on the table

Comment: In sheet1, after using a filter, a table is created with X columns (companies) and Y rows (date), based on this table I am creating a correlation matrix (like table2) in sheet2 with the same number of columns (companies) from sheet1..

Comment: Based on the table created on sheet1, I want to automate the process of building the correlation matrix in sheet2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166870/discussion-between-robin-hcp-and-qharr).